# Field calculating a unique date and time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser

I want to field calculate a field to be have a have the date and time (down to the second) and two letters after (to be assigned by user).

For example, if the record was created on September 8th, 2016 at 7:15 am and 03 seconds it would look like this: `090816071503XX`

I also need this to be unique though, in some cases this field calculate will be performed on over 5000 records. By doing a complete field calculate in real-time, this means all 5000 records would show the same time. So I need a code that will field calculate a "fake", but realistic time (i.e. can't have hour 25). I don't care that this time is incorrect, but I do want the date to be correct.

I imagine this is something that can be scripted in Python?

I have a VBA (.cal) script I can load into the field calculator which will calculate the date and time, but as I said, I need it to return unique times.

```
'enter your initials  
INIT="XX"  

'month string - add zero  
If LEN(DatePart ("m", Now (  ) ))=1 then  
    MO = "0"&DatePart ("m", Now (  ) )  
Else  
    MO = DatePart ("m", Now (  ) )  
end if  


'day string - add zero  
If LEN(DatePart ("d", Now (  ) ))=1 then  
    DA = "0"&DatePart ("d", Now (  ) )  
Else  
    DA = DatePart ("d", Now (  ) )  
end if  

'year string - two digits  
YR = RIght(DatePart ("YYYY", Now (  ) ),2)  

'HR string - two digits  
If LEN (DatePart ("h", Now (  ) ))=1 then  
    HR = "0"&DatePart ("h", Now (  ) )  
Else  
    HR = DatePart ("h", Now (  ) )  
End if  

'MN string - two digits  
If LEN (DatePart ("n", Now (  ) ))=1 then  
    MN = "0"&DatePart ("n", Now (  ) )  
Else  
    MN = DatePart ("n", Now (  ) )  
End if  

'SS string - two digits  
If LEN (DatePart ("s", Now (  ) ))=1 then  
    SS = "0"&DatePart ("s", Now (  ) )  
Else  
    SS = DatePart ("s", Now (  ) )  
End if
```

Comment: Yes this is something that can be done with python in field calculator or model builder or entirely in python with update cursors.  If you try writing some code people will be glad to check it for you and help, we just dont like to do other peoples work entirely for them.  If you already have a field that is holding the date (i cant tell if this is the case, or you need to calculate a date and insert it) you would convert field to string, concatenate that field with a user defined string parameter for the XX.

Comment: Ok I added some script that I had started, it's in vba.

Comment: Whats the problem with the script?  What errors?  I am out in the field on a phone right now, when I get to a PC I can better look at it.

Comment: The script field calculates the real date and time, meaning there would be duplicates. I need to force it to calculate a correct date, but a false and unique time.

Comment: see this : http://www.extension.iastate.edu/communities/sites/www.extension.iastate.edu/files/communities/PM2082-09n.pdf

Comment: That was super helpful, thank you. I updated my code for it and I'm pretty happy with it but I'm still not getting completely unique numbers. The link you sent is for a random generator, which I thought would be close enough to getting unique values (especially considering I was setting the minimum to be 12000 and the max to be 17000), but on a set of 750 records I ended up with two duplicates. It takes less than 2 minutes to identify those duplicates and manually fix the value, but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid that altogether.

Answer (score 6):

The above answer works, but seems a bit overcomplicated.  Why not just this:

Code Block:

```
import datetime
dateSet = set()

def set_date(timestamp, suffix):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    global dateSet

    while date in dateSet:
        date += datetime.timedelta(0,1)
    dateSet.add(date)
    return datetime.datetime.strftime(date, "%m%d%y%H%M%S{}".format(suffix))
```

And the expression:

```
set_date("09/16/2016 14:22:57", "MM")
```

This printed out `'091616142257MM'` for me.  It is also worth noting, if you have an actual Date Field, it should return a `datetime.datetime()` and you could skip the conversion from the string timestamp by just using `datetime.datetime.strftime(date, "%m%d%Y%H%M%S{}".format(suffix))`.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

EDIT:

I see part of the OP is asking for a unique time.  I borrowed from @Midavalo's answer to add the time delta to make it unique.

Comment: +1 I got myself a bit tied up once I started - yours is the efficient answer I was aiming for

Comment: The question is does the result need to be unique for the calculation or for the whole feature class? This is nice code (+1 by the way) but there is still a potential to have duplicates in the data if only selected rows are calculated, you might need to incorporate (somewhere) a check for count of features (like summary statistics) - but perhaps I'm overthinking this and the whole table will be calculated; if not the potential for duplication is *very* small but still warrants checking.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I had considered but discarded that point due to the OP's comment "if the record was created on"  from which I assumed that this was record creation date/time and so you'd only have that date and time on initial calculation for each record, and not for any future records.

Comment: And yes I do know what they say about when we "assume" anything

Comment: You're probably right @Midavalo, I'm probably overthinking a very simple problem... just been burned by 'creation time *and* unique' stipulation previously in a multi-user edit environment and I remember how much fun it wasn't locating and fixing up the duplicate records.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson it probably wouldn't take much more to include a Search Cursor and set to find the values that already exist to completely avoid duplicates

Comment: @Midavlo, I know what you mean.  I often get tunnel vision and do something similar.  I liked your addition with the timedelta to make sure it was unique.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson that is a good point about checking for the entire data set for duplicates.  That is where it would probably be best to use an `UpdateCursor` against the `datasource` of the input to get at all the rows.

Answer (score 5):

Using the field calculator with python parser:

In the Code Block:

```py
import datetime
initials = 'MM'
dateSet = set()

def set_date(thedate):
    def date_string(myDate):
        myYear = str(myDate.year)[2:]
        myMonth = str(myDate.month).zfill(2)
        myDay = str(myDate.day).zfill(2)
        myHour = str(myDate.hour).zfill(2)
        myMinute = str(myDate.minute).zfill(2)
        mySecond = str(myDate.second).zfill(2)
        return {'Year': myYear, 'Month': myMonth, 'Day': myDay, 'Hour': myHour, 'Minute': myMinute, 'Second': mySecond}

    global dateSet
    myDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(thedate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    dd = date_string(myDate)
    dateStr = "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}".format(dd['Month'], dd['Day'], dd['Year'], dd['Hour'], dd['Minute'], dd['Second'])

    while dateStr in dateSet:
        myDate += datetime.timedelta(0,1) 
        dd = date_string(myDate)
        dateStr = "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}".format(dd['Month'], dd['Day'], dd['Year'], dd['Hour'], dd['Minute'], dd['Second'])
    dateSet.add(dateStr)

    return "{}{}".format(dateStr, initials)
```

And in the Expression:

```py
set_date('09/16/2016 14:22:57')
```

(where `09/16/2016 14:22:57` is the date you want to add to the field)

Calculate Field tool:

[image]

Result:

[image]

This just adds a second to the time if it has already been used.